# How do I add a custom tab to my Facebook profile (not to a page!)?

Tags: facebook

There are plenty of apps and tutorials out there for adding custom content into a tab for a page.

But how do I add a custom tab to my actual profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook removed the ability to add custom tabs to a personal profile page some time ago.  (They can still be added to a Page.)  However, Facebook is in the process of rolling out [Timeline](https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline), which replaces your personal profile page, and which does allow apps that are specially built for Timeline.  Once you have switched from a profile page to Timeline you will be able to add these apps to your timeline.

Further details can be found here:
https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=105925952849619

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that facebook has removed this feature based on this hints in this article: http://blog.soundcloud.com/2010/01/15/facebook/